How to fill a color in hand drawn shape or closed path in rough js?
I am using RoughJs ( docs ) for my whiteboard app. I have done programming the work of tools like - pencil button, undo button, redo button, clear canvas button, color picker, But struggling to program the fill color button.
In simple words, I want that after selecting fill color button and a color from color picker
It fills color wherever I left click with the mouse on the canvas that's all.
CODE
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import rough from 'roughjs'
const roughGenerator = rough.generator()



const WhiteBoard = ({ canvasRef, ctxRef, elements, setELement, tool, color }) => {
  const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2
    ctx.strokeStyle = color
    ctx.lineWidth = 2
    ctx.lineCap = "round"
    ctxRef.current = ctx
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    ctxRef.current.strokeStyle = color
  }, [color])

  console.log('in elements', elements);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (canvasRef) {
    const roughCanvas = rough.canvas(canvasRef.current)

    // removes clock effect with lines
    if (elements.length > 0) {
      ctxRef.current.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height)
    }

    elements.forEach(element => {

      switch (element.type) {
        case "pencil":
          roughCanvas.curve(element.path, {
            roughness: 0,
            curveStepCount: 20,
            bowing: 0.2,
            strokeWidth: 5,
            disableMultiStroke: true,
            stroke : element.stroke,
          })
          break;
      default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
  }, [elements])

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent

    switch (tool) {
      case "pencil":
        setELement((prevElement) => [
          ...prevElement,
          {
            type: "pencil",
            offsetX,
            offsetY,
            path: [[offsetX, offsetY]],
            stroke: color
          }
        ])
        break;

      default:
        console.log("error in match down handler");
        break;

    }

    setIsDrawing(true)
  }

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = e.nativeEvent
    if (isDrawing) {
      switch (tool) {
        case "pencil":
          // exract all paths from last element and add more paths like [200,201] to it

          const { path } = elements[elements.length - 1]  // [[1,2],[12,42]]
          const newPath = [...path, [offsetX, offsetY]]

          // adding more paths in last element of elements
          setELement((prevElement) =>
            prevElement.map((ele, index) => {
              if (index == elements.length - 1) {
                return {
                  ...ele,
                  path: newPath
                }
              } else {
                return ele
              }
            })
          )

          break;
        default:
          console.log("error in move handler match");
          break;
      }
    }
  }

   
  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    console.log("up", e);
    setIsDrawing(false)
    console.log("elements", elements);
  }


  return (
    <div
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      className='border border-dark border-3 w-100 h-100 overflow-hidden'
    >
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>

  )
}

export default WhiteBoard;

You can see a demo in image.

